# How do I spread an object (class instance properties) to the parent's super constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How can I spread a class properties to the parent's super constructor?

ActionLog is a base class, it's instantiated in a method inside ActionRequestAccess

**ActionRequestAccess.ts**

```
export class ActionRequestAccess extends ActionLog {
  constructor(public actionLog: ActionLog, public customerId: string) {
    super(
      actionLog.id, // Want to get rid of these assignments <<< and switch to something like: ...actionLog
      actionLog.type,
      actionLog.date,
      actionLog.address,
      actionLog.location
    );
  }

  static override fromMap(map: any) {
    if (!map) {
      return null;
    }
    const baseMap = super.fromMap(map);
    if (!baseMap) {
      return null;
    }
    return new ActionRequestAccess(baseMap, map['customerId'] ?? null);
  }
}
```

**ActionLog.ts**

```
import { ActionType } from '../../enums';

export class ActionLog {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public type: ActionType,
    public date: Date,
    public address: string,
    public location: string
  ) {}

  static fromMap(map: any) {
    if (!map) {
      return null;
    }
    return new ActionLog(
      map['id'] ?? null,
      map['type'] ?? null,
      map['date'] ?? null,
      map['address'] ?? null,
      map['location'] ?? null
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just add a constructor to `ActionLog` that takes an `ActionLog`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values` on the object inside `ActionRequestAccess`.

```
 constructor(public actionLog: ActionLog, public customerId: string) {
    super(...Object.values(actionLog));
  }
```

But this means that the order the values of your object are passed to the function mathers, so this pattern is a little bit unsafe. This will work

```
const myObject = new ActionRequestAccess({
    id: 1,
    type: 'myType',
    date: 'myDate',
    adress: 'myAdress',
    location: 'myLocation',
});
```

but this will switch the position of the id and type and will not work.

```
const myObject = new ActionRequestAccess({
    type: 'myType',
    id: 1,
    date: 'myDate',
    adress: 'myAdress',
    location: 'myLocation',
});
```

If you can change the expected value to the constructor of `ActionLog` to be an object instead of parameters, then that will probably be easier and more safe.

Comment: Thing is, If I change the values to an object, I'll lose the returning class instance.
I think I forgot to mention, the "map: any" property is a firebase snapshot, so I need to map through It and return any missing field as null.

Spreading the Object.values seems the way, I'll keep the post updated, thanks.